# React embedded in .NET Razor

Tags: reactjs, razor, react-scripts

I create a new react app with "dotnet new react" This has a .net core api, and a react frontend, and an index.html. It has  tag and it includes the minified javascript output of react-scripts build, something like this:

this is a perfect standalone app for testing.

my problem is that this whole thing should be embedded into my existing legacy Razor application. The legacy code has a Layout.cshtml, and a React.cshtml where the react code should be added.

So when I commit the code, the deployment process should call react-scripts build, create the minified js, somehow recognise the hash, and put it into the React.cshtml. Or I can rename it or course to a hardcoded filename, bit that also requires a script to add in deplyment. 
Or I could embed the index.html into my React.cshtml, but I don't think that is a very nice solution

Is there a nicer way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can only "directly embed" so to say Vue.js into Razor pages, Angular/React can currently be only as full blown SPA applications.
Usually I go with an approach to create landing page, about page etc. in Razor (or some other template engine) mostly for SEO purposes and from there I direct users to SPA which is the "meat part" of application.

Comment: Hi! Could you please expand on "directly embed vue" statement? I am looking for information on this topic, this is the second time I have met this idea, but can't figure out how to implement it (I do react most of the time). Any good reads maybe? Thanks

Comment: Hi, searching with keywords as `vue + jquery` will give you plenty of articles, as for [example](https://css-tricks.com/making-the-move-from-jquery-to-vue/)